# Referencing earlier passages: Cross reference or "as discussed earlier" (stylistic)

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I am looking for stylistic advice regarding the (over) use of cross-references. I hope this is not off-topic. Using cross-references through `\ref{...}` for major structural blocks like chapters and sections certainly is a good idea. But when it comes to subsections or subsubsection that are only one or two pages long, technical cross-references begin to feel a little over the top and I prefer using phrases such like *as mentioned earlier* or *as discussed in the previous section* (while possibly actually meaning a latex subsubsection). I also prefer it this way, as I don't like numbered headings for subsections and subsubsections, for the same reason: It looks overkill. But numbered headings are requiered for the cross-references to work.

So, should I rather use technical cross-references with `\ref{...}` throughout the text? Are the more or less agreed upon stylistic rules for this in scientific writing?

Comment: Check `hyperref` package's `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` commands.

Comment: Hm okay, but what is that supposed to tell me? I am not asking a technical question but a stylistic one.

Comment: Sorry ... I thought that it was technical... Stylistic questions usually are supposed to be (and marked as)  "too broad" in this site. It is about LaTeX and not about general typography rules or styles.

Comment: Okay, then I will repost it on academia stackexchange.

Comment: @lotolmencre Please post the link to your question here once done, so that interested people can check the answers you'll receive. :-)

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/133325/referencing-earlier-passages-cross-reference-or-as-discussed-earlier/133327#133327